# WPF's BitmapCache is not completely cleared

Tags: .net, wpf, path, bitmap, rendering

We have a WPF Page with a user control where we use a BitmapCache - when we try to clear this element by updating the property (Data Binding) with an empty Path (New Path()), it is not completely refreshed/cleared. If I change the window size a little bit the area where the BitmapCache is active is completely cleared.

Is there something special to do to clear/refresh an element that uses BitmapCache?

This is our code:

```
    <me:ScrollViewer
    RenderedWaves="{Binding RenderedWaves}"
    ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplateForWaveItem}" 
    ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ItemsPanelTemplateForWaveItems}" 
    CacheMode="BitmapCache" />
```

**I thought I fixed it, but it works not every time...**

This code to set the path doesn't update the BitmapCache immediately:

```
Protected WriteOnly Property SetGraph As Path
 Set(value As Path)
    If value Is Nothing Then value = GetEmptyPath()
    _graph = value
    OnPropertyChanged(New PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyNameGraph))
 End Set
End Property
```

And this code updates it sometimes:

```
Protected WriteOnly Property SetGraph As Path
Set(value As Path)
    UIDispatcherLocator.UIDispatcher.Invoke(Sub()
                                                If value Is Nothing Then value = GetEmptyPath()
                                                _graph = value
                                            End Sub, Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background)
    OnPropertyChanged(New PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyNameGraph))
End Set
End Property
```

Comment: You may tell us a bit more? Why so complicated?

Comment: If I were a betting man I'd say you have vidya card issues.  Can you provide a minimal example that repros?

Comment: You could call InvalidateVisual() from code-behind, to see if that helps

Comment: You have to change the UIElement subtree or these properties (EnableClearType\RenderAtScale) to cause the cache to be regenerated....see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2009/11/10/new-wpf-features-cached-composition.aspx

Comment: @colinsmith Yes, that is what I do, I change some Path elements that are bound to that control, but the BitmapCache is not refreshed instantly (first after I manual resize the window with my mouse).

Comment: @Will It is difficult to provide a minimal example... It's a part of a big project and I have no idea where I could "cut" it...

Comment: @ekholm I tried to set InvalidateVisual() when the Path and it's Geometry is empty but that doesn't work

Comment: Instead of putting CacheMode on the ScrollViewer, put it on the "panel" you are using in the ItemsPanelTemplateForWaveItems template. ... then after that try this.....do a _graph = null (Nothing in VB); OnPropertyChanged(New PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyNameGraph))..then the _graph = value; and OnPropertyChange again.

Comment: @colinsmith Thanks for the idea - it works much better than before, but it leads to other problems (the size of the element changes, when graphs are added). I have to figure out, weather this is a connected problem or not..

Answer (score 0):

could you have just made a new event on the object to fire when needed and when called would set object = to new object that was created temporary by a use statement if you could make it inherit from system.idisposable or if you just set it to null when done? I don't know the code for it off the top of my head but something like:

```
MyEvent += new event(object b);

event(object b)
{
  using (custom_ScrollViewer = new custom_ScrollViewer)
{ 
OnScreen_ScrollViewer = Custom_ScrollViewer;

}; 
// or 
custom_ScrollViewer = new custom_ScrollViewer;
OnScreen_ScrollViewer = Custom_ScrollViewer;
custom_ScrollViewer = null;

}
```